# Why can't I run my queried data in a for-loop?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I pulled my Opportunity data from Salesforce via apex. All the data is populating correctly, but when I try to run though it all using a for-loop I get a error message?

**The error message:**

[image]

**My JS Code:**

```
export function MapMarkers(SearchCity, SearchState, SearchStreet, Opportunities){

    const ArrAddress = [];
    const ArrCity = [];
    let index = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {

        if(index === 10){

            break;

        }

        const ArraySplit = Opportunities[index].Service_Address__c.split('<br>');

        ArrAddress[i] = ArraySplit[0];
        ArrCity[i] = ArraySplit[1];

        index++;

    }
```

**Refined Question:**

I am splitting the string every time `'<br>'` is read. Since for `Service_Address__c` its string is:

`"address'<br>'town/state'<br>'United States"`

I want to split the string and record all 9 **address** to `ArrAddress[]`, and all 9 **town/state** to `ArrCity[]`.

Also is there away to get the 9 most recent Opportunities for this?

Comment: You still have not included enough information in the post for anyone here to even guess what `Opportunities` is or why `Opportunities[index]` is undefined. We are not mind readers; you need to include a complete enough code sample for the community to understand and reproduce the issue.

Comment: `Opportunities` is the array that has all the queried data. I made a edit showing it's not undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Opportunities` has only 9 elements, then in your loop, once `index` reaches 9, it will try and read the 10th element from the array (`Opporunities[9]`), but this will be undefined.

In your code `index` and `i` are always going to be equal so I'd suggest just using one of them and writing your for-loop as follows:

`for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++)`

Comment: You're correct it doesn't make any sense to have `index`, I removed it and changed my for-loop to how you shown it. But I am still getting the error message from above?

Comment: Use i < 9 as your end condition and not i < 10. (I have updated my answer)

Comment: Just made that change, still getting the error; sadly.

Comment: How many elements are in your Opportunities list?

Comment: Oh, I see. I was only using 5 elements, in the future I want to use 9 that's why.

Comment: Glad you found it! You could do i < Opportunities.length && i < 9 as your end condition in that case

Answer (score 2):

You can use `slice` to get the initial 10 records, and some other methods for getting the data out. `slice` will return up to ten entries for you, so you don't need to worry about keeping track of indexes.

```
let top10opportunities = Opportunities.slice(0, 10);
let tempData = top10opportunities.map((opp) => opp.Service_Address__c.split('<br>'));
let streets = tempData.map((data)=>data[0]);
let cities = tempData.map((data)=>data[1]);
```

Here, we use `map` to convert our data from one form to another. The first call returns a new array that looks like:

```
[
  ['Street','City','Country'],
  ...
]
```

The second map call pulls out just the first element of each array, which we put into the `streets` variable. Likewise, the third map gets our cities. There's likely at least a dozen efficient ways we could write this, I just decided to use this one. You'll find the map function is indispensable once you've learned how to use it.

I recall that you're new to JavaScript, so I'd recommend especially reading up on [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). It's a lot more powerful than you might imagine.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, this is very helpful.

Comment: Instead of getting the "initial 10 records", how would I be able to get the "most recent 10 records"? Is that a special function, or something todo with the array?

Comment: @Pinto you could use `slice(-10)`, which would be up to the last ten entries, or the entire array if less than 10.